# Search through a collection for documents which have a partial string in an array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a collection which has a bunch of documents which look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d1d3e2b31da89828d0b194"),
    "ihash" : "15e1e4b84492fe6f",
    "firstseen" : ISODate("2017-03-22T01:31:14.405Z"),
    "lastseen" : ISODate("2017-03-22T14:01:25.792Z"),
    "names" : [ 
        "carrot", 
        "apple", 
        "banana"
    ]
}
```

and I want to search through my collection to find all documents which contain "rr" in the list of names.

Any help with this would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mongo regex (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).
From the mongo console:

```
db.collection.find({ "names" : /rr/ })
```

or alternatively

```
db.collection.find({ "names" : {"$regex": /rr/ }})
```

You may want to check out the documentation for other options that are supported such as case-insensitive, matching anchors (`^` for the start, `$` for the end of the string), and others if your needs require it.